# Can this function be expressed with a generator comprehension?

Tags: python, generator

I have the following function:

```
def infinite_sequence(starting_value, function):
    value = starting_value
    while True:
        yield value
        value = function(value)
```

Is it possible to express this as a generator comprehension? If we were dealing with a fixed range, instead of an infinite sequence, it could be dealt with like so: *(Edit: actually that's wrong)*

```
(function(value) for value in range(start, end))
```

But since we're dealing with an infinite sequence, is it possible to express this using a generator comprehension?

Comment: It's *almost* `itertools.accumulate`, but with enough differences to make emulating one with the other more pain than it's worth. I don't think there is a generator expression, especially not one that reads better than this very simple and idiomatic function.

Comment: Terminology note: there is no such thing as a generator comprehension. You are looking to use a generator *expression*, which syntactically looks like a *list* comprehension.

Comment: Why not leave it as a function?

Answer (score 1):

You would need some sort of recursive generator expression:

```
infinite_sequence = itertools.imap(f, itertools.chain(x, __currentgenerator__))
```

where `__currentgenerator__` is a hypothetical magic reference to the generator expression it occurs in. (Note that the issue is not that you want an infinite sequence, but that the sequence is defined recursively in terms of itself.)

Unfortunately, Python does not have such a feature. Haskell is an example of a language that does, due to its lazy argument evaluation:

```
infinite_sequence = map f x:infinite_sequence
```

You can, however, still achieve something similar in Python 3 while still using a `def` statement, by defining a recursive generator.

```
def infinite_sequence(f, sv):
    x = f(sv)
    yield from itertools.chain(x, infinite_sequence(f, x))
```

(`itertools.chain` isn't strictly necessary; you could use

```
def inifinite_sequence(f, sv):
    x = f(sv)
    yield x
    yield from infinite_sequence(f, x)
```

but I was attempting to preserve the flavor of the Haskell expression `x:infinite_sequence`.)

Comment: You could use `accumulate` off-label, e.g. `f=lambda x: 2*x+1; start_val=0; list(islice(accumulate(repeat(start_val), lambda x,_: f(x)), 10))`.

Answer (score 0):

This is `itertools.accumulate`, ignoring all but the first value:

```
from itertools import accumulate, repeat

def function(x): return x*2
start = 1

seq = accumulate(repeat(start), lambda last, _: function(last))
```

Just write it out in full, though.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, just use an infinite iterator such as [`itertools.count`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.count).

```
(function(value) for value in itertools.count(starting_value))
```

Comment: -1 That yields `f(0)`, `f(1)`, `f(2)` instead of `0`, `f(0)`, `f(f(0))`, `f(f(f(0)))` (with `starting_value = 0` for simplicity).